# How to grow the intuition behind this proof?

Tags: probability, random-variables, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions, neural-networks

> My intension is to understand this complete proof step by step in a lucid manner. I am trying few days to capture this, Unfortunatly I am failed. Can I hope to get a nice intuitive explanation of this proof. Looking forward to get such a answer. Thanks in advance.

[Paper Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.12806)

---

Theorem 2. Let $\left(x_{1}, y_{t}\right)$ be i.i.d. input-output pairs in $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times[-1,1]$ such that:

1. The distribution $\mu$ of the covariates $x_{t}$ can be written as $\mu=\sum_{\ell-1}^{k} \alpha_{\ell} \mu_{\ell}$, where each $\mu_{\ell}$ satisfies $c$-isoperimetry and $\alpha_{\ell} \geq 0, \sum_{\ell-1}^{k} \alpha_{\ell}=1$.
2. The expected conditional varianoe of the output is strictly positive, denoted $\sigma^{2}:=\mathbb{E} \mu[V a r[y \mid x]]>0$.
   Then one has:
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   &\mathbf{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{t}-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon\right) \\
   &\leq 4 k \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3} k}\right)+2 \exp \left(\log (|\mathcal{F}|)-\frac{e^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right)
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   We start with a lemma showing that, to optimize heyond the noise level one must necessarily correlate with the noise part of the labels. In what follows we denote $g(x)=\mathbb{E}[y \mid x]$ for the target function, and $z_{i}=y_{t}-g\left(x_{i}\right)$ for the noise part of the observed labels (namely $y_{1}$ is the sum of the target funetion $g\left(x_{i}\right)$ and the noise term $z_{1}$ ).
   Lemma 2.1. One has
   $$
   \mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{t}-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-E\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{n t^{2}}{g^{3}}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{1} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right)
   $$
   Proof. The sequence $\left(z_{1}^{2}\right)$ is i.i.d., with mesn $\sigma^{2}$, and such that $\left|z_{1}\right|^{2} \leq 4$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yielde:
   $$
   \mathbf{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{1}^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{g^{3}}\right)
   $$
   On the other hand the sequence $\left(z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right)\right)$ is i.i.d., with mean $0\left(\right.$ since $\left.\mathbb{E}\left[z_{i} \mid x_{\mathrm{f}}\right]=0\right)$, and such that $\left|z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right)\right| \leq 2$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yields:
   $$
   \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i-1}^{n} z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right) \leq-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{\pi t^{2}}{g^{3}}\right)
   $$
   Let us write $Z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(z_{1}, \ldots, z_{n}\right), G=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(g\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, g\left(x_{n}\right)\right)$, and $F=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(f\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, f\left(x_{n}\right)\right)$. We claim that if $\|Z\|^{2} \geq \sigma^{2}-\frac{6}{6}$ and $\langle Z, G\rangle \geq-\frac{6}{6}$, then for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$ one has
   $$
   \|G+Z-F\|^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon \Rightarrow\langle F, Z\rangle \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}
   $$
   This claim together with $(2.1)$ and $(2.2$ ) conclude the proof. On the other hand the claim itself directly follows from:
   $$
   \sigma^{2}-\epsilon \geq\|G+Z-F\|^{2}=\|Z+G-F\|^{2}=\|Z\|^{2}+2\langle Z, G-F\rangle+\|G-F\|^{2} \geq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}-2\langle Z, F\rangle
   $$
   We can now proceed to the proof of Theorem $2$

Proof. First note that without loss of generality we can assume that the range of any function in $\mathcal{F}$ is included in $[-1,1]$ (indeed elipping the values improves both the fit to any $y \in[-1,1]$ and the Lipechitz constant). We also assume wlog that all funetions in $\mathcal{F}$ are $L$-Lipechitz.

For clarity let us start with the case $k=1$. By the isoperimetry assumption we have that $\sqrt{\frac{d}{c}} \frac{\left(z_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E} / \Omega}{L}$ is 1-sulygamssian. Since $\left|z_{i}\right| \leq 2$, we also have that $\sqrt{\frac{d}{c}} \frac{\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}\left|\int\right| z_{i}\right.}{L}$ is 4 -subgaussian. Moreover, the latter random variable has zero-mean since $\mathbb{E}[z \mid x]=0$. Thas by Proposition ${ }^{2} 2$ we have:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt{\frac{d}{c \pi L^{2}}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq t\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-(t / 9)^{2}\right)
$$
We rewrite the above as:
$$
\mathbf{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right)
$$
Since we assumed that the range of the functions is in $[-1,1]$ we have $\mathbb{E}[f] \in[-1,1]$ and hence:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[f] z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{1}\right| \geq \frac{E}{8}\right)
$$
(This step is the analog of requiring the labels $y_{1}$ to be well-balanced in the example of perfect interpolation.) By Hoeffding's inequality, the sabove quantity is smaller than $2 \exp \left(-n e^{2} / 8^{3}\right)$ (recall that $\left.\left|z_{t}\right| \leq 2\right)$. Thus we obtain with an union bound:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right) & \leq|F| \cdot \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \\
& \leq 2|F| \cdot \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right)+2 \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Together with Lemma $2 . .1$ this concludes the proof for $k=1$.
We now turn to the case $k>1$. We first sample the mixture component $\ell_{1} \in[k]$ for each data point $i \in[n]$, and we now resson conditioned on these mixture components. Let $S_{\ell} \subset[n]$ be the set of data points sampled from mixture component $\ell \in[k]$, that is $T_{t}, i \in S_{\ell}$, is i.i.d. from $\mu_{\ell}$. We now have that $\sqrt{\frac{d}{c}} \frac{\rho\left(x_{i}\right)-\mathbb{E}^{\mu_{l_{i}}}}{}$ which depends on the mixture component). In particular using the same ressoning as for (2.4) we obtain (crucially note that Proposition $4.2$ does not require the random variables to be identically distributed):
$$
\mathbf{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(f\left(x_{1}\right)-\mathbb{E}^{\mu_{e_{i}}}[f]\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon^{2} n d}{9^{4} c L^{2}}\right)
$$
Next we want to appropriately modify (2.4). To do so note that:
$$
\max _{\left.m_{1}, \ldots, m_{k} \in \mid-1,1\right]} \sum_{i=1}^{n} m_{\ell} z_{i}=\sum_{\ell-1}^{k}\left|\sum_{i \in S_{R}} z_{t}\right|
$$
so that we ean rewrite (24) as:
$$
\mathbf{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}^{\mu \ell_{i}}[f] z_{i} \geq \frac{E}{8}\right) \leq \mathbf{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\left|\sum_{i \in S_{\ell}} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{E}{8}\right)
$$

Now note that $\sum_{\ell=1}^{k} \sqrt{\left|S_{\ell}\right|} \leq \sqrt{n k}$ and thus we have:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\left|\sum_{i \in S_{\ell}} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\left|\sum_{i \in S_{\ell}} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8} \sqrt{\frac{n}{k}} \sum_{\ell=1}^{k} \sqrt{\left|S_{\ell}\right|}\right) \leq \sum_{\ell=1}^{k} \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i \in S_{\ell}} z_{i}\right| \geq \frac{\epsilon}{8} \sqrt{\frac{n}{k}} \sqrt{\left|S_{\ell}\right|}\right)
$$
Finally by Hoeffding's inequality, we have for any $\ell \in[k], \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i \in S_{\ell}} z_{i}\right| \geq t \sqrt{\left|S_{\ell}\right|}\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{t^{2}}{8}\right)$, and thus the last display is bounded from above by $2 k \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3} k}\right)$. The proof can now be concluded as in the case $k=1$.

---

**Edit 1** :- As per comment section, I will shoot my doubt step by step eventually that integrate to a complete solution I guess.

**DOUBT 1**:-

> Theorem $12.3$ (Hoeffding inequality) Given independent $\left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$ with $X_{i} \in\left[a_{i}, b_{i}\right]$ a.s.,
> $$
> \operatorname{Pr}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i}\left(X_{i}-\mathbb{E} X_{i}\right) \geq \epsilon\right] \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n^{2} \epsilon^{2}}{\sum_{i}\left(b_{i}-a_{i}\right)^{2}}\right)
> $$
> How this proof gears using that theorem, moreover there is a "$\geq$" in original proof. I am unable to find the catch.

Proof. The sequence $\left(z_{1}^{2}\right)$ is i.i.d., with mesn $\sigma^{2}$, and such that $\left|z_{1}\right|^{2} \leq 4$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yielde:
$$
\mathbf{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{1}^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{g^{3}}\right)
$$

Comment: You have just copied out the whole proof. If you want help, you must specify *what you want help with*

Comment: A step by step explanation of whole proof, What I have understood is not satisfying my inner quest, hence have posted here.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @FShrike.  The *proof* consists of several steps, some of which I would guess that you understand/accept the validity of.  So, I suggest that you overhaul your question.  Remove the proof, posted so far, copying the proof onto a piece of scratch paper.  Then, go to the very first step, that you are unsure of, and only present that step in your posting, with the question of : *Why is this step valid?*  Then, once you are satisfied, go to the next step in the proof where you have a question, and make a separate MathSE posting from that.

Comment: I think it’d be useful to include the title and authors of the paper in the question. That will make it easier for other readers of the paper to google for this.