# How to proof this lemma using Hoeffding Inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality, random-variables, proof-explanation

This question follows from a previously [asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439236/how-to-grow-the-intuition-behind-this-proof). I am trying to understand the proof of Lemma 2.1 in the paper ["A Universal Law of Robustness via isoperimetry"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12806.pdf) by Bubeck and Sellke.

We start with a lemma showing that, to optimize heyond the noise level one must necessarily correlate with the noise part of the labels. In what follows we denote $g(x)=\mathbb{E}[y \mid x]$ for the target function, and $z_{i}=y_{t}-g\left(x_{i}\right)$ for the noise part of the observed labels (namely $y_{1}$ is the sum of the target funetion $g\left(x_{i}\right)$ and the noise term $z_{1}$ ).
Lemma 2.1. One has
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{t}-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right).......(A^{1})
$$
Proof. The sequence $\left(z_{1}^{2}\right)$ is i.i.d., **with mean $\sigma^{2}$**, and such that $\left|z_{i}\right|^{2} \leq 4$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yielde:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{1}^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)......................(1)
$$
On the other hand the sequence $\left(z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right)\right)$ is i.i.d., with mean $0\left(\right.$ since $\left.\mathbb{E}\left[z_{i} \mid x_{\mathrm{f}}\right]=0\right)$, and such that $\left|z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right)\right| \leq 2$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yields:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i-1}^{n} z_{i} g\left(x_{i}\right) \leq-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)$$

I am typically got stuck in the 1st step of proof of this lemma.
I have read about Hoeffding's inequality ,but unable to sync.

For reference

> Theorem $12.3$ (Hoeffding inequality) Given independent $\left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$ with $X_{i} \in\left[a_{i}, b_{i}\right]$ a.s.,
> $$
> \operatorname{Pr}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i}\left(X_{i}-\mathbb{E} X_{i}\right) \geq \epsilon\right] \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n^{2} \epsilon^{2}}{\sum_{i}\left(b_{i}-a_{i}\right)^{2}}\right)
> $$

---

**Edit 1**

Theorem 4 (Hoeffding's inequality). Let $Z_{1}, \ldots, Z_{n}$ be independent bounded random variables with $Z_{i} \in[a, b]$ for all $i$, where $-\infty<a \leq b<\infty$. Then
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Z_{i}-\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{i}\right]\right) \geq t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n t^{2}}{(b-a)^{2}}\right)
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Z_{i}-\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{i}\right]\right) \leq-t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n t^{2}}{(b-a)^{2}}\right)
$$
for all $t \geq 0$.

Using the 2nd one I am able to reach here ,

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(z_{i}^2-\mathbb{E}\left[z_{i}^2\right]\right) \leq-t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n t^{2}}{(b-a)^{2}}\right)
$$

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^2-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[z_{i}^2]\right) \leq-t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n t^{2}}{(b-a)^{2}}\right)
$$

as $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[z_{i}^2] = \sigma^2(mean) $$

Replacing the value of it

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^2- \sigma^2 \leq-t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n t^{2}}{(b-a)^{2}}\right)
$$

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^2 \leq \sigma^2 -t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n t^{2}}{(b-a)^{2}}\right)
$$

Thus comparing with Eq $1$, I am getting the  value of $t$ as $\epsilon/6$. **And it is given** $\left|z_{i}\right|^{2} \leq 4$.
So We can rewrite it as $ -4 \leq z_{i} ^{2} \leq 4$. So $a$ = -4 and $b$ = 4

Plugging it into RHS ,

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^2 \leq \sigma^2 -t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{2 n \epsilon^{2}}{(4+4)^{2}*36}\right)
$$

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^2 \leq \sigma^2 -t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{ n \epsilon^{2}}{(4+4)^{2}*18}\right)
$$

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^2 \leq \sigma^2 -t\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{ n \epsilon^{2}}{(8)^{2}*18}\right)
$$

**But RHS is not matching with $Eq 1$. I am unable to figure it out , where am I wrong. Can anyone help me out?**
(Solved)

---

**Edit 2**

> $$
> \mathbf{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{1}^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right).....................(2.1)
> $$
> On the other hand the sequence $\left(z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right)\right)$ is i.i.d., with mean $0\left(\right.$ since $\left.\mathbb{E}\left[z_{i} \mid x_{\mathrm{f}}\right]=0\right)$, and such that $\left|z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right)\right| \leq 2$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yields:
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i-1}^{n} z_{1} g\left(x_{1}\right) \leq-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)...........(2.2)
> $$
> Let us write $Z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(z_{1}, \ldots, z_{n}\right), G=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(g\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, g\left(x_{n}\right)\right)$, and $F=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(f\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, f\left(x_{n}\right)\right)$. We claim that if $\|Z\|^{2} \geq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}$ and $\langle Z, G\rangle \geq-\frac{\epsilon}{6}$, then for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$ one has
> $$
> \|G+Z-F\|^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon \Rightarrow\langle F, Z\rangle \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}......(2.3)
> $$

This claim together with $(2.1)$ and $(2.2$ ) conclude the proof of $A^{1}$ How?? And how they have written the eq ($2.3$)

**I have clearly understood Eqn 2.1 and 2.2 but after that how they conclude the proof I am not getting, Kindly help me to understand**

Comment: Hoeffding inequality has two part, see "Concentration Inequalities", http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/mlss_conc.pdf

Comment: Have used, but failed to reach final conclusion :(

Comment: Please do not edit your already answered question to ask another one on top. If you another question to ask, do it in a separate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write :

> **And it is given** $\left|z_{i}\right|^{2} \leq 4$.
> So We can rewrite it as $ -4 \leq z_{i} ^{2} \leq 4$. So I can let $a = -4$ and $b = 4$

Although this is not wrong in itself, you can do much better.

Indeed, $z_i^2$ is nonnegative, so the tighter lower bound is $a=0$ instead of $-4$. If you replace with that value of $a$, Hoeffding's inequality now yields :
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^2 \leq \sigma^2 -\frac\epsilon 6\right) &\leq \exp \left(-\frac{ 2n \epsilon^{2}}{4^2\cdot 6^{2}}\right)\\
&=\exp \left(-\frac{ n \epsilon^{2}}{2^3\cdot 6^2}\right)\\
&\le \exp \left(-\frac{ n \epsilon^{2}}{8^3}\right)
\end{align} $$
Where the last inequality directly follows from the observation that $2^3\cdot6^2<8^3 $.