# How the Lemma is concluded using those three inequalities?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality, solution-verification, random-variables

With reference to this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439678/how-to-proof-this-lemma-using-hoeffding-inequality)

Lemma 2.1. One has
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-f\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon\right) \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(x_{i}\right) z_{i} \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4}\right) .
$$
Proof. The sequence $\left(z_{i}^{2}\right)$ is i.i.d., with mean $\sigma^{2}$, and such that $\left|z_{i}\right|^{2} \leq 4$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yields:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right) .........(2.1)
$$
On the other hand the sequence $\left(z_{i} g\left(x_{i}\right)\right)$ is i.i.d., with mean 0 (since $\mathbb{E}\left[z_{i} \mid x_{i}\right]=0$ ), and such that $\left|z_{i} g\left(x_{i}\right)\right| \leq 2$. Thus Hoeffding's inequality yields:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i} g\left(x_{i}\right) \leq-\frac{\epsilon}{6}\right) \leq \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^{2}}{8^{3}}\right) .........(2.2)
$$
Let us write $Z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(z_{1}, \ldots, z_{n}\right), G=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(g\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, g\left(x_{n}\right)\right)$, and $F=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(f\left(x_{1}\right), \ldots, f\left(x_{n}\right)\right)$. We claim that if $\|Z\|^{2} \geq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}$ and $\langle Z, G\rangle \geq-\frac{\epsilon}{6}$, then for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$ one has
$$
\|G+Z-F\|^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon \Rightarrow\langle F, Z\rangle \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4} ........(2.3)
$$

**Proof of this claim** :-  On the other hand the claim itself directly follows from:
$$
\|G+Z-F\|^{2}=\|Z+G-F\|^{2}=\|Z\|^{2}+2\langle Z, G-F\rangle+\|G-F\|^{2}= \|Z\|^{2}+2\langle Z,G\rangle -2\langle Z,F\rangle+\|G-F\|^{2}  \geq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{6}-2\frac{\epsilon}{6}-2\langle Z, F\rangle .\geq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}-2\langle Z, F\rangle .
$$

one has
$
\|G+Z-F\|^{2} \leq \sigma^{2}-\epsilon$  and We have just now proved $\|G+Z-F\|^{2} \geq \sigma^{2}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}-2\langle Z, F\rangle $

This implies :-
$$ \Rightarrow\langle F, Z\rangle \geq \frac{\epsilon}{4} $$

> **This claim together with (2.1) and (2.2) conclude the proof.**

How They are concluding the *lemma 2.1* with the help of these three equations , I am unable to come up with,

Comment: "Equations"? Let's see... presumably you are not including the definitions of "$Z$", "$G$" and "$F$". So that leaves $$\mathbb{E}\left[z_{i} \mid x_{i}\right]=0\\\|G+Z-F\|^{2}=\|Z+G-F\|^{2}\\\|Z+G-F\|^{2}=\|Z\|^{2}+2\langle Z, G-F\rangle+\|G-F\|^{2}\\\|Z\|^{2}+2\langle Z, G-F\rangle+\|G-F\|^{2}= \|Z\|^{2}+2\langle Z,G\rangle -2\langle Z,F\rangle+\|G-F\|^{2}$$ Everything else is inequalities. Which of these are the three equations you are referring to?

Comment: I have updated the question. Now "Z" , "G" and "F" are defined. I am referring to 2.1 , 2.2 and 2.3